# Create C Array in Swift and Pass its Pointer to a C Function (in Swift)

Tags: arrays, c, swift, pointers

Given the type

```c
struct thin_header {
    uint32_t offset;
    uint32_t size;
    struct mach_header header;
};
```

and the following function signature

```c
struct thin_header *headersFromBinary(struct thin_header *headers, NSData *binary, uint32_t *amount);
```

I would like to convert the following code into Swift

```c
struct thin_header headers[4];
uint32_t numHeaders = 0;
headersFromBinary(headers, binary, &numHeaders);
```

So far, I have done the following

```swift
var headers = thin_header()
var numHeaders = UInt32()
headersFromBinary(&headers, binary, &numHeaders)
```

However, I do not believe this makes sense because `headers` should really be an array of `thin_header`s. This code does compile and causes no errors at runtime, but how would I be able to loop through the array of thin_headers?

Comment: I've updated my answer for two reasons.  The first is that I didn't actually answer the question of how to call `headersFromBinary`.  The second is that I did a quick refresher on Mach-O headers, so my answer needed some small revisions.

Comment: @ChipJarred thank you very much for the very detailed answer!!

Comment: You're welcome.  In the iteration loop toward the end of my answer, I'm assuming that `thin_header.size` is the number of bytes that includes `thin_header` itself.  If only the size of the actual `mach_header`, then you'll need to change the `MemoryLayout` reference to use `mach_header` and `mach_header_64`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing Mach-O parsing are we?

Basically you're not going to be able to do something as simple as making an array of thin headers.  It's been a while since I've looked at the Mach-O format specs but I think they follow the fairly common C technique of defining structs that have some common information at the start, but differing length information thereafter, so where you have `mach_header` it could actually be a `mach_header_64` and you have to use the `size` field to determine which.

So you basically you need to be able to advance by byte counts but then look at any given location as your thin header.  You'll also need to define different structs for the different header types if you want to look at anything other than `size` and `offset`.

```swift
struct ThinHeader
{
    let offset: UInt32
    let size: UInt32
}

struct FatHeader32
{
    let thinHder: ThinHeader
    let restOfHder: mach_header
}

struct FatHeader64
{
    let thinHder: ThinHeader
    let restOfHder: mach_header_64
}
```

So to use the C API you give, you have to do a bit of fakery:

```swift
var machoHeaderData = Data(repeating: 0, count: MemoryLayout<fat_header64>.stride * maxHeaders)

var amount: UInt32 = dhrData.count // I assume that's what this is supposed to be
machoHeaderData.withUnsafeMutableBytes
{
    $0.withMemoryRebound(to: thin_header.self)
    {
        _ = headersFromBinary(&$0, ptrToBinary, &amount)
    }
}
```

Now `machoHeaderData` will contain the bytes of the array returned by `headersFromBinary`.

```swift
machoHeaderData.withUnsafeBytes
{
    var rawHdrPtr = $0.baseAddress
    for _ in 0..<numHeaders
    {
        let size = rawHdrPtr!.bindMemory(to: ThinHeader.self, capacity: 1).pointee.size
        if size == MemoryLayout<FatHeader64>.size
        {
            let hdrPtr = rawHdrPtr!.bindMemory(to: FatHeader64.self, capacity: 1)
            doSomethingWithHeader64(hdrPtr.pointee)
        }
        else
        {
            assert(size == MemoryLayout<FatHeader32>.size)
            let hdrPtr = rawHdrPtr!.bindMemory(to: FatHeader32.self, capacity: 1)
            doSomethingWithHeader32(hdrPtr.pointee)
        }
        
        rawHdrPtr = rawHdrPtr!.advanced(by: size)
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could just assume it's a `FatHeader32` type and rebind to `FatHeader64` when size indicates. You save a `bind` to `thin_header` first, not that it's an expensive call.  Just a matter of preference, I suppose.

The code above assumes that the `size` field in `thin_header` is the number of bytes in the actual header data, but the actual correct way to determine the size of a Mach-O header is by checking its `magic` field.  It's value indicates the size

- `MH_MAGIC` indicates `mach_header` in native byte-order
- `MH_CIGAM` indicates `mach_header` in swapped byte-order
- `MH_MAGIC_64` indicates `mach_header_64` in native byte-order
- `MH_CIGAM_64` indicates `mach_header_64` in swapped byte-order

Pointers in Swift kind of suck to use... that's actually on purpose, to discourage their use, while acknowledging that they are sometimes necessary.  It also means Swift will never displace C for systems programming, especially at the kernel level.

Answer (score 0):

To convert the C code directly into Swift, I would write something like this:

(Assuming you have prepared `binary` as `Data`.)

```
var headers: [thin_header] = Array(repeating: thin_header(), count: 4)
var numHeaders: UInt32 = 0
headersFromBinary(&headers, binary, &numHeaders)
```

> but how would I be able to loop through the array of thin_headers?

Making `headers` an Array as above, you can loop through it.